# How can i identify whether the value from the database is null or not in .Net 2.0?

Tags: oracle, c#-2.0

I am fetching the data from the database and populate it into the domain object.Lets say

```
    public class A
    {
        int? ai;

        public int? AI
        {
            get { value = ai;}
            Set { ai = value; }

        }

    }
```

so i am creating the domain object in the main class.

```
    class TestClass
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            class A objData = new A();
    // here some logic for creating connection to the database and calling the datareader to fetch the //data.
        int temp =(int) objDataReader["aiDAta"];
        objData.ai = temp == null? 0: temp;
        func(objData);

     }
    }

public void func(A objData)
{

// Here i want to display the value of  objData.ai only if its database value is not null.since i was   //already assigned 0,if the value from the database is null...how can i able to identify whether the value  //from the database is null or not? also,In database "aiDAta" will have the value range from 0 - 99.
}
```

}

Here i want to display the value of  objData.ai only if its database value is not null.since i was already assigned 0,if the value from the database is null...how can i able to identify whether the value from the database is null or not? also,In database "aiDAta" will have the value range from 0 - 99.

Answer (score 2):

Compare objData.ai to

```
DBNull.value
```

instead of NULL

or

check

```
IsDBNull(objData.ai)
```

or

```
public Int32 TryCastInteger32(object value)
{
    if (value != null && !Information.IsDBNull(value)) {
        Int32 retVal = default(Int32);
        if (Int32.TryParse(value.ToString(), out retVal)) {
            return retVal;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your casting to a Nullable checked the HasValue property. It will be true only is the value type is not null.

Comment: i was assigning "0",if the value from the database is null in the Main()

Comment: If you want to convserve the "It was null in the database" information, allow the nullable<int> to do its job, and simply store the null reference.  You did declare it that way after all.

Answer (score 0):

Usually null DB fields are returned as System.DbNull in which case the following cast will fail:

```
int temp =(int) objDataReader["aiDAta"];
```

You can use [DBDataReader's IsNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.isdbnull.aspx) method to check for a null value before using it

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you could also just let the database validate if the value is null or not by creating an oracle function and passing the value you want it to evaluate:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
  FUNCTION isNull(
      i_value IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    IF i_value IS NOT NULL THEN
      RETURN 1;
    ELSE
      RETURN 0;
    END IF;
  END;
  /
```

Comment: Sorry, but not a good idea, you can handle the null in .net by "DBNull.value" or "IsDBNull".